# Django CreateAPIView not showing creation Form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Working with the Django REST Framework i encountered quite a big problem.
**Here is what my problem looks like**:
[CreateAPIView not showing Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HweRI.png)

What I currently have at **serializers.py**:

```
class TaskCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  # Create
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title')
```

At **views.py**:

```
class TaskCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):  # Create
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskCreateSerializer
```

And at **urls.py**:

```
path('tasks/create/', TaskCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='create_tasks')
```

So basically i can't create any task objects

What I tried:

```
class TaskCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  # Create
    title = serializers.CharField()  # New line (does not work)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma in fields tuple. Either use list,  or  ('title', ). Otherwise,  in Python it is just a string in parentheses. Maybe that's the issue.  Also you have to choose POST method in the drop down at top-right. 
Just noticed,  are you sure about "v1"  part of URL? Maybe it shouldn't be there,  it looks like this URL is not being resolved at all.

Comment: ('title',) or 'title' didn't resolved the problem. I am sure about the 'v1' as part of the URL. And the drop down you mention doesn´t have a POST method option

Comment: Can you add relevant parts of route setup please? Do your have another routes starting with /tasks? My thought is that your DetailView is placed before CreateView and catches the URL, because it has tasks/<id>,  and then it can't find the Task with id "create".

Comment: Wow that was exactly it! Thank you a lot! **Changing to a different url like 'create/task/' solved my problem**